# Could not find a matching version of package magento/product-community-edition

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, magento2.2.6

I am working on the upgrade process of Magento from version 2.1.9 to 2.2.6.

When I run the below command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
```

I got below error:

```
Could not find a matching version of package magento/product-community-edition. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (alpha).
```

I am following the below document:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

What is going wrong here?

following is my **composer.json**...

```
    {
    "name": "magento/magento2ce",
    "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.9",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
        "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "2.7.7",
        "zendframework/zend-code": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-server": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-soap": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-uri": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-validator": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-crypt": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-console": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-text": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-i18n": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-view": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-json": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-config": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-form": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-di": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-serializer": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-log": "~2.4.6",
        "zendframework/zend-http": "~2.4.6",
        "magento/zendframework1": "~1.12.16",
        "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.6",
        "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "1.2",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.9",
        "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "1.4",
        "composer/composer": "<=1.0.0-beta1",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.16.0",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.7.0",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "0.1.1",
        "tubalmartin/cssmin": "2.4.8-p4",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
        "braintree/braintree_php": "3.7.0",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3 <2.7",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
        "symfony/process": "~2.1",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
        "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.0.1",
        "magento/composer": "~1.0.0",
        "lib-libxml": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-spl": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-xsl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.1.9",
        "mailchimp/mc-magento2": "^1.0",
        "msp/recaptcha": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-marketplace": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-authorization": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-authorizenet": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-backup": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-braintree": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-bundle": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-captcha": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-catalog": "101.0.9",
        "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-catalog-search": "100.1.7",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-catalog-widget": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-checkout": "100.1.8",
        "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-cms": "101.0.7",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-config": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-configurable-product": "100.1.9",
        "magento/module-contact": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-cookie": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-cron": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-currency-symbol": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-customer": "100.1.8",
        "magento/module-customer-import-export": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-deploy": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-developer": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-dhl": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-directory": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-downloadable": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-eav": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-email": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-encryption-key": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-fedex": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-gift-message": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-google-analytics": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-google-optimizer": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-grouped-product": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-import-export": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-indexer": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-integration": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-media-storage": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-msrp": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-multishipping": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-newsletter": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-offline-payments": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-page-cache": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-payment": "100.1.7",
        "magento/module-paypal": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-persistent": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-product-alert": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-product-video": "100.1.6",
        "magento/module-quote": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-reports": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-require-js": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-review": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-rss": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-rule": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-sales": "100.1.8",
        "magento/module-sales-rule": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-sales-inventory": "100.1.1",
        "magento/module-sales-sequence": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-search": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-security": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-send-friend": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-shipping": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-sitemap": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-store": "100.1.7",
        "magento/module-swagger": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-swatches": "100.1.8",
        "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-tax": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-tax-import-export": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-theme": "100.1.7",
        "magento/module-translation": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.1.7",
        "magento/module-ups": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-user": "100.1.3",
        "magento/module-usps": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-variable": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-vault": "100.2.2",
        "magento/module-version": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-webapi": "100.1.4",
        "magento/module-webapi-security": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-weee": "100.1.2",
        "magento/module-widget": "100.1.5",
        "magento/module-wishlist": "100.1.6",
        "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "100.1.2",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.1.6",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.1.7",
        "magento/language-de_de": "100.1.1",
        "magento/language-en_us": "100.1.1",
        "magento/language-es_es": "100.1.1",
        "magento/language-fr_fr": "100.1.1",
        "magento/language-nl_nl": "100.1.1",
        "magento/language-pt_br": "100.1.1",
        "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "100.1.1",
        "magento/framework": "100.1.9",
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
        "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7"
    },
    "extra": {
        "component_paths": {
            "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
            "components/jquery": [
                "lib/web/jquery.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
            ],
            "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
            "components/jqueryui": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
            ],
            "twbs/bootstrap": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
            ],
            "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the composer.json file to the question

Comment: please check i have updated my question wih compose.json file

Comment: I am not sure about the issue, but may be some of those module/packages has Magento itself as required. If you try to upgrade the project and keep those you will face problems you can check those module/packages.

Answer (score 17):

These 2 things worked for me

1. I needed to add the repository reference to my composer.json because it wasn't there

   ```
   "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "composer",
               "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
           }
       ],
   ```
2. I needed to rename my auth.json.sample to auth.json and add the public and private keys to the json.

   ```
   {
       "http-basic": {
           "repo.magento.com": {
               "username": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
               "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
           }
       }
    }
   ```

If you want to input your private and public keys manually then do not include the auth.json

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** This popped up on my Google feed and I foolishly didn't look at the date on it. Oh well.

You didn't install Magento through the composer meta package, so you can't use that meta package to upgrade your system.

There are alternative methods to install Magento outlined in their documentation. You'll need to figure out which one was used to install it and follow that style of upgrade, OR, reset your install to use the meta package and port your customizations over.

When using the meta package you should have one requirement that provides all the other Magento packages for you (Magento/product-community-edition). Your composer config shows you're pulling individual pieces in instead of one meta package.

If you really want to use the meta package (and I recommend it) then you may need to "start fresh" and move your customizations over. Basically I would run the composer create project command and install it in a new directory. Then copy the composer.json file to old installation and add in all the custom requirements I had (e.g. themes, modules) and run the composer update command.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing auth.json file. Sometime it works!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple, I was facing same issue since hours of struggle I got answer. **if your composer file is ok than you must upgrade your composer to 2 it will work fine and resolves iss.**

```
updae composer using this cmd:composer self-update --2
```

Cheers,
Zahid